# Android: playing video in Webview using HTML 5

Tags: android, html, video, webview, sd-card

I wanted to play video in webview using html page. i created html page and kept in asset folder and video are stored in sdcard.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am not able to play the video.

Comment: Did you solved your problem?!

Answer (score 0):

see https://gist.github.com/3718414 for a sample which plays video in a webview. It shows how to either reference the HTML as a URL or assemble it inline.
you will need to make sure that you also take note of the permissions mentioned in the comments

Comment: setPluginState is deprecated.